# How to allow special character '/' in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<xs:attribute name="genre">

    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="sci/fi"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:attribute>
```

Is sci/fi a valid string value? if not, how do i represent the fraction slash (/) ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to find out the answer by using a validator?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen No, i had no idea what a validator is until today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/ is not a special character in xml. the characters < > & " ' are the only special characters. Hence sci/fi is a valid string.

Comment: So sci/fi is a valid string value?